# a-frame error 'core: a-assets warn Asset loading timed out 3000ms

Tags: vue.js, aframe

```
    <a-scene environment="preset: forest">
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="duck" src="./assets/duck.glb"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>
      <a-entity gltf-model="#duck" position="-4 -4 -4"></a-entity>
      <a-entity
        camera
        position="-1.946 2.807 -3.552"
        wasd-controls
        look-controls
      >
      </a-entity>
    </a-scene>
```

```
!error message!
core:propertyTypes:warn "#duck" asset not found. 
http://localhost:8080/assets/duck.glb 404 (Not Found)
aframe-master.js?ce54:2199 core:a-assets:warn Asset loading timed out in   3000 ms
```

I'm trying to connect `a-frame` with `Vue`, but I can't get a file from the `asset`. I keep getting that error, but I haven't been able to solve it at all. I'm not used to `a-frame`, so I need help. Please help me.

And another question is, I set the `environment="preset: forest"` property, but when I open the server, the environment property is not working. What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 2):

By default, asset loading time is set to 3seconds. Setting a custom timeout for fairly large assets solved it for me.

```
<a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="duck" src="./assets/duck.glb" timeout="10000"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it has not been resolved :(

Comment: Then try inspect element on chrome. And go to the networks tab and check the disable cache box and re run the system

Comment: Unsure about other versions, but 1.4.0 says timeout is a property of the wrapping a-assets element: https://aframe.io/docs/1.4.0/core/asset-management-system.html#setting-a-timeout